# Vapor/Leaf Custom Tag not returning correct value

Tags: swift, vapor, leaf

I have registered a custom tag to return true if the index is odd and false if even as follows:

```
class OddEvenTag: BasicTag {
    let name = "OddEven"

    func run(arguments: ArgumentList) throws -> Node? {
        guard
            arguments.count == 1,
            let index = arguments[0]?.int
            else { return Node(nil) }
        print(index, index & 1)
        return Node((index & 1) == 1)
    }
}
```

The print statement produces satisfyingly good output:

```
0 0
1 1
2 0
3 1
...
```

However, when I use the custom tag inside a #loop in a leaf file, such as

```
#OddEven(offset){hello}##else(){bye}
```

It always instantiates the hello. I've tried hard-coding false into the return statement and it doesn't change the outcome. I have used a (more complex) custom tag before, so I know they can work.

In case you're wondering, I really want to use the tag to alternate the row background colours of a grid!

Comment: If I just use #OddEven(index) int the leaf file, then it includes the text strings 'true' and 'false'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `BasicTag` can only be used like this:

```
#TagName(variable)
```

and returns a value.

If you want to conditionally render a following block like this:

```
#TagName(variable) { show if true }
```

then you need to extend `Tag`, and put your show/hide code in the `shouldRender(tagTemplate:arguments:value:)` function.

As a starting point, look at the [`If` tag](https://github.com/vapor/leaf/blob/master/Sources/Leaf/Tag/Models/If.swift), but instead of testing for true values, test for even values.